# Jquery to insert content after Bootstrap row end

Tags: jquery, html

My template based on Bootstrap and I have 12 Icons each 4 in a row,
I made an simple tab jquery code and my problem that the hidden content show under the all 12 Icons.

What I want to do is:
When I click the Icon, its hidden content will show in under the same Icon and the rest icons in the same row in single row with 12 column.

So, each row when we click any Icon of it, new row will appear below it with the relative hidden content.

So the jQuery should insert the hidden content just after the Bootstrap row ended and before the new one start (between)

My HTML/JS code I added it to this link:

```
<!--  https://jsfiddle.net/xoomserve/ej97rqLs/ -->
```

Forgave my English and I hope someone can help me.

Thank you,
Tariq

Comment: Is there a reason why you have the contents in their own section?  If you alter your HTML and move the `<div id="hpt1-content" class="properties-cats hide">` right under `<span id="hpt1" class="home-tabs inactive col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">` your content would show up between tab1 and tab2

Comment: Thank you, The problem that I have otherr view for the mobile that why I have this section and in mobile working fine, I just wonder how to dynamic inert it after each row end

Comment: `.insertAfter()` should do the job for this.  Try adding this snippet inside your else block `$("#" + tId + "-content").insertAfter($(this)); `

Comment: Thank you again, its came to the same point. Insert after will just insert it after the relative dive which will break the view, this is exactly whatI did in the mobile view. But in this case, I really need to find a code insert it after the row itself finish so the content will take full row, got the point?